# What does a veterinarian do?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know that a veterinarian takes care of animals, but what is the action called?

For example, a painter paints, a programmer writes programs, and a surgeon performs surgeries. What does a veterinarian do?

Comment: "What is it that you do?"  

"I'm a butler, sir.  I butle."

Comment: What does a doctor do? What does a blacksmith do? etc etc. Not every analogy is filled out.

Answer (score 1):

A veterinarian is someone who practices ***veterinary medicine.***

**Examples in Sentence**

- Veterinary medicine is a branch of medicine.
- The dog could only be saved through the use of veterinary medicine.

So what is a veterinarian?

> Besides medical skills, veterinarians often take a holistic approach to human well-being and animal welfare that, combined with communications and problem-solving skills, makes veterinarians uniquely qualified to fulfill a variety of roles. Many veterinarians, of course, provide care for companion animals through private medical practices, but veterinarians are also involved in promoting the health and welfare of farm animals, exotic animals, working animals (like those in the equine industry), and those that need a healthy environment in which to thrive, whether that environment is a rain forest, a desert or even the ocean.

Source: http://aavmc.org/Students-Applicants-and-Advisors/Careers-in-Veterinary-Medicine.aspx

Comment: Would this be suitable in a context such as "he practices veterinarian medicine on the animals"?

Comment: @questioner Yes, it would be suitable. Veterinarian medicine is a branch of medicine.

Comment: I think "_veterinary medicine_" is the preferred term over "veterinarian medicine."  Google has trouble finding any examples of  "veterinarian medicine."

Comment: @questioner: "veterinary medicine" refers to animal care. Then adding "on the animals" is a pleonasm.

Comment: Yes, you're correct @Exal Veterinary is the correct way of saying it; mishap on my part to point out the distinction - will include in post.

Comment: And one of these days, with enough practice, he'll get it right.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Isn't that what he wrote? "Practices is a third person verb, is it not? In the US English **practices** is a verb.

Comment: Oops - Apologies. I got the US spelling the wrong way around!  In British English the noun and verb are spelled differently. In US English they are spelled the same.

Comment: @questioner - Instead of  "he practices veterinary medicine on the animals" consider "he practices animal medicine" or "he practices veterinary medicine" using both words  is redundant.